# Passing props from child to parent

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

I've got a side-nav.js which has the list of categories of items, I want to grab the categoryid and pass it to the parent layout.js, then to the parent of layout.js -> customer.js.

Currently I'm getting the following error

> ncaught TypeError: props.setSelectedCategory is not a function
> at onClick (side-nav.js?99b7:91:25)

side-nav.js

```
 {categories.map(category => (
              <SideNavItem
                key={category.id}
                title={category.name}
                onClick={()=> {console.log("Clicked category:", category.id);
                  props.setSelectedCategory(category.id)}}
              />
```

layout.js

```
export const Layout = (props) => {
  const { children, selectedCategory } = props;
  const pathname = usePathname();
  const [openNav, setOpenNav] = useState(false);

  const handlePathnameChange = useCallback(
    () => {
      if (openNav) {
        setOpenNav(false);
      }
    },
    [openNav]
  );

  useEffect(
    () => {
      handlePathnameChange();
    },
    // eslint-disable-next-line react-hooks/exhaustive-deps
    [pathname]
  );

  return (
    <>
      <TopNav onNavOpen={() => setOpenNav(true)} />
      <SideNav
        onClose={() => setOpenNav(false)}
        open={openNav}
        setSelectedCategory={props.setSelectedCategory} // Pass setSelectedCategory as a prop
        selectedCategory={selectedCategory}
      />
      <LayoutRoot>
        <LayoutContainer>
          {React.cloneElement(children, { selectedCategory: selectedCategory || 0 })}
        </LayoutContainer>
      </LayoutRoot>
    </>
  );
};
```

customer.js. I have removed the unnessary code here. When the page first loads, it gets selectedcategory = 0 as it is still undefined, after customer.js detects a change in selectedcategory's value, in useffect, it should display the new set of products. I have trouble getting the new selectedcategory at the moment.

```
 const CustomerPage = (props) => {
    
   
     const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(0);
    
      useEffect(() => {
      console.log("selectedcat" , selectedCategory)
        //todo props change
        let url;
        if ( selectedCategory !== 0)
          url ='http://localhost:8282/product/categeory/${selectedCategory}'
        else if ( selectedCategory === 0)
          url = 'http://localhost:8282/product/all'
        console.log("url " + url)
    
        fetch(url)
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setProducts(data);
          });
    
        fetch('http://localhost:8282/product/reviews/all')
          .then(response => response.json())
          .then(data => {
            setReviews(data)
          });
    
        console.log("reviews,", reviews)
      }, [selectedCategory]);
    CustomerPage.getLayout = (page) => (
  <CustomerLayout
    setSelectedCategory={page.props.setSelectedCategory}
    selectedCategory={page.props.selectedCategory}
  >
    {page}
  </CustomerLayout>
);

export default CustomerPage;
```

Full code below without backend
https://codesandbox.io/p/github/Fennzo/IncedoFront/master?workspaceId=2cfdb890-0378-4eb6-9f13-bd958dd39483

Answer (score 0):

The state variable and the setter function should be should "lifted up" from the child components to the parent CustomerPage component so they can be "passed down" to the child components as props-

```
const CustomerPage = (props) => {
// Other code
    const [selectedCategory, setSelectedCategory] = useState(0);
    return (
    <Layout setSelectedCategory={setSelectedCategory} selectedCategory={selectedCategory} {...props} />
  )
}
```

Also try a console.log(setSelectedCategory) in all the components that use it so you can get a better idea of what's going on and why it's saying it's not a function.

Also, it looks like you're using single quotes '' for the url in CustomerPage in the

```
if ( selectedCategory !== 0)
```

block instead of using backticks `` and so the string interpolation won't work correctly

Comment: I do a console log in the customerpage's useeffect for setselectedcategory and it shows the following. I've updated the customerpage with the code you gave but it's still showing the same error

setselectedcategory ƒ dispatchSetState(fiber, queue, action) {
  {
    if (typeof arguments[3] === 'function') {
      error("State updates from the useState() and useReducer() Hooks don't support the " + 'second callback…